# How to add a extra values for the keys on dictionaries?

Tags: swift, dictionary

For the following variable

```
var dict2 = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : [ "value1" , "value2" ]]
```

How to add a third value for the second key of the following dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I can reformulate your `dict2` declaration slightly:

```
var dict2 = ["key1" : ["value1"], "key2" : [ "value1" , "value2" ]]
```

then you can append an extra item to `key2` like this:

```
dict2["key2"]?.append("value3")
```

However, you will probably need to be careful to check that `key2` was already present.  Otherwise, the above statement will do nothing.  In which case you can write:

```
if dict2["key2"]?.append("value3") == nil {
    dict2["key2"] = ["value3"]
}
```

Why did I change the original declaration?  With the version I gave, `dict2` will be of type `[String:[String]]`.  But with your version, what Swift is doing is declaring a much more loosely typed `[String:NSObject]`.  This compiles, but behaves *very* differently (contents will have reference not value semantics, you will have to do type checks and casts frequently etc), and is probably best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

@AirspeedVelocity provides a working solution, but requiring a small change to the way the data is defined - but that is what I would do myself, if possible.

However if you have to stick with the original data format, you can use this code:

```
var dict2: [String : AnyObject] = ["key1" : "value1", "key2" : [ "value1" , "value2" ]]

var array = dict2["key2"] as? [String]
array?.append("value3")
dict2["key2"] = array
```

First we make explicit the `dict2` type, a dictionary using strings as keys and `AnyObject` as values.

Next we extract the value for the `key2` key, and attempt to cast to an array of strings - note that this returns an optional, so the type of `array` is `[String]?`

In the next line we add a new element to the array - note that if `array` is `nil`, the optional chaining expression evaluates to `nil`, and nothing happens

In the last line, we set the new `array` value back to the corresponding key - this step is required because the array is a value type, so when we extract it from the dictionary, we actually get a copy of it - so any update made on it won't be applied to the original array.